# Finding out which script that is enabling a Boolean or changing a variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a Unity Developer and I'm quite new, I sometimes have a problem where a script changes on a Boolean/variable, and it can be quite annoying to look through 20 scripts to find it and sometimes I just cant find it.

I was wondering if anybody knows how to set something up that shows me where a variable is changed from or if anybody has a good solution I can use. I have tried `Debug.Log` and sometimes it works but when I cant find the script it becomes useless.

Comment: Try using getter and setter functions?

Comment: When you're on your variable, you can simply press F12 (if you're using Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what IDE (where you write your code) you are using, there is a function which shows you all places where a variable/field is used.

On Visual Studio you can right-click the variable and show all references (see screenshot) to that variable in your code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I put a debug.log($"Value changed by XXXX function") so I can see whats going on at runtime or to see if a certain action is causing the change.